# mysql price compare, show all prices in a join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, compare

I have a `MySql` product table called `babyfoontest` where all my products are listed like this:

```
idnummer | ean | typenummer | merk

1        | 1111| Baby1      | Philips

2        | 2222| Baby2      | Alecto
```

and I have a big price table called `prijzen` with all prices from different `webshops` like this:

```
idnummer | shopnaam | typenummer | price | eancode | producturl | categorie

1        | Amazon   | Baby1      | 9,99  | 1111    | www.test.nl| baby

2        | Amazon   | Baby2      | 19,99 | 2222    | www.test.nl| baby

3        | BCC      | Baby1      | 17,99 | 1111    | www.test.nl| baby
```

Now on my results page, I want to show `5` products with a price comparison. In my product table, every `EAN` is `unique`. I want to match it with all the `EAN` numbers from the price table and show all prices from `min` to `max`. How can I do this?

In the example above if the first product is on the result page, `Baby1`, I want to prices to show `(9,99 AND 17,99)` because they match on `EAN`.

I have this:

```
SELECT *
FROM babyfoontest
INNER JOIN prijzen
ON babyfoontest.ean = prijzen.eancode
LIMIT 0, 5
```

So the tables match, but now I get only one price from the `prijzen` table, and I need all the prices from that product. I use this foreach loop:

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($data as $info) {
echo $i;
echo ' asd '.$info->typenummer.'<br>';
echo 'asd '.$info->producturl.'<br>';
echo 'asd '.$info->deeplink.'<br>';
echo 'asd '.$info->eancode.'<br><br>';
$i++;
}
```

Please help me with this!

Thanks!!

Kind regards,
Mark

Comment: I can not see `$info->price` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to concatenate the prices together.  Something like this:

```
SELECT b.ean, group_concat(p.price order by p.price) as prices
FROM babyfoontest b INNER JOIN
     prijzen p
     ON b.ean = p.eancode
GROUP BY b.ean
LIMIT 0, 5
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for your answer. I've tried it but it takes a long while to load to page now. Also I need the price, producturl and the shopnaam from the prijzen table so I can show all prices with logo and deeplink for the 5 products. Is this possible? Thanks so much for helping me out!